# Term for an adjective that is part of a name

Tags: adjectives

What is or is there a term for an adjective that is part of a name? For example Big John, Grand Canyon - are Big, Grand adjectives, just part of the name, or something else?

Comment: Just part of the name, like _The Commonwealth of Virginia_ or _The Peoples' Republic of China_

Answer (score 1):

epithet

> adjective or phrase that is used to express a characteristic of a person or thing, such as Ivan the Terrible ([Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/epithet))

Comment: I looked at the definition of epithet and thought it was my answer. But all of the examples followed the name and seemed to select a particular person rather than describe them. "the Terrible" appears to choose a specific Ivan. "Big" just describes John.